# Erro java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException ao fazer thumbnail de video

Tags: java

Estou tentando criar um thumbnail de um vídeo usando JCodec.jar.
Na minha máquina "localhost", funciona perfeitamente, porém ao tentar fazer o mesmo processo no servidor. obs: Estou usando um servidor Debian ele dá erro e me retorna este log.
Se alguém, puder ajudar fico agradecido, tenho quase certeza que o problema é permissão porém não sei como resolver.

```
java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /usr/share/tomcat7/c6340371082696266598.mp4
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
        at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:317)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createFile(Files.java:588)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(TempFileHelper.java:138)
        at java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(TempFileHelper.java:161)
        at java.nio.file.Files.createTempFile(Files.java:805)
        at br.com.academia.bean.ExercicioBean.uploadVideo(ExercicioBean.java:505)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:264)
        at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278)
        at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
        at org.primefaces.component.fileupload.FileUpload.broadcast(FileUpload.java:318)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:755)
        at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(UIViewRoot.java:931)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:78)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provavelmente isto é um erro de permissão no sistema de arquivo.

Tente dar permissão de escrita e leitura para com o comando abaixo como root:
**chmod 766 /usr/share/tomcat7**

Comment: Consegui resolver o problema de outra forma, obrigado amigo!